# C# : XNA4 : SpriteSortMode on X-axis sorts at random?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm working on a tile/sprite-based game, calling my Draws via

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        DrawBehind(spriteBatch);
        DrawEven(spriteBatch);
        DrawInFront(spriteBatch);
    }

    private void DrawBehind(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        ActiveMap.DrawAtDepth(spriteBatch, Player, 1);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }

    private void DrawEven(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, null);
        ActiveMap.DrawAtDepth(spriteBatch, Player, -1);
        Player.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }

    private void DrawInFront(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        ActiveMap.DrawAtDepth(spriteBatch, Player, 0);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

As expected, DrawBehind and DrawInFront just draw based on the order they are called, stable and well on both X and Y.

DrawEven sorts on the Y-axis correctly, but on the X-axis, the sprites just seem to flip in front of eachother and back for no apparent reason.

If it would be stable, I don't really care in which order it sorts it. Instead, everytime I "move my character" (move the position of all the sprites but my character's), it flickers and switches all around. Anyone knows what causes this or how to fix it?

As per request

EDIT:

Map:

```
public void DrawAtDepth(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Player player, int depth)
    {
        Area.DrawAtDepth(spriteBatch, player, depth);
    }
```

Area:

```
public void DrawAtDepth(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Player player, int depth)
    {
        const int border = 10;
        var screenTiles = new Rectangle(
            0 - border,
            10 - border,
            (GameMain.ScreenRectangle.Width / Tile.Width - 1) + border,
            (GameMain.ScreenRectangle.Height / Tile.Height - 1) + 10 + border);

        var playerLevelPosition = player.LevelPosition;

        for (int layer = 0; layer < _layerCount; layer++)
            if (ActiveLevels[1, 1].GetLayerDepth(layer) == depth)
                for (int y = screenTiles.Y; y < screenTiles.Height; y++)
                    for (int x = screenTiles.X; x < screenTiles.Width; x++)
                        Draw(spriteBatch, player, playerLevelPosition, layer, x, y);
    }
private void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Player player, Vector2 playerLevelPosition, int layer, int x, int y)
    {
        int levelX;
        var tileX = TilePos((int)playerLevelPosition.X, Level.Width, x, out levelX);

        int levelY;
        var tileY = TilePos((int)playerLevelPosition.Y, Level.Height, y, out levelY);

        var level = ActiveLevels[levelX, levelY];

        if (level != null)
            level.Draw(spriteBatch, player, layer, new Vector2(tileX, tileY));
    }

    private float TilePos(int playerPos, int mapBounds, int offset, out int levelPos)
    {
        var tilePos = ((playerPos) - (mapBounds/2f - 1)) + offset;

        levelPos = 1;
        if (tilePos < 0)
        {
            levelPos = 0;
            return tilePos + mapBounds;
        }
        if (tilePos >= mapBounds)
        {
            levelPos = 2;
            return tilePos - mapBounds;
        }
        return tilePos;
    }

    public static float GetDepth(float tilePos)
    {
        return 1 - tilePos / (Level.Height * 3);
    }
```

Layer:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 tile, Vector2 drawPosition, Color color, bool transparent = false)
    {
        if (_grid[(int)tile.X, (int)tile.Y] == null) return;
        _grid[(int)tile.X, (int)tile.Y].Draw(spriteBatch, drawPosition, color, transparent, (Depth != -1) ? Depth : Area.GetDepth(Level.Height + tile.Y));
    }
```

Tile:

```
public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 drawPosition, Color color, bool transparent = false, float depth = 0)
    {
        if (!GameMain.ScreenRectangle.Intersects(_sprite.Bounds)) return;

        if (transparent && _fade)
            color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 100);

        spriteBatch.Draw(
            _sprite,
            drawPosition,
            null,
            color,
            0,
            new Vector2(_sprite.Width / 2 - Width / 2, _sprite.Height),
            1,
            SpriteEffects.None,
            depth
            );
    }
```

Also, any general tips for the sake of it are welcome. I'm a pretty new programmer, styling tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with the latest XNA 4, so this might not be -the- correct answer, but:

From the symptoms you describe and the fact that it's only happening when you set the BackToFront SpriteSortMode, I would expect that you're either not setting a depth coordinate for some of the sprites being drawn in DrawEven or not making them different enough. As such, I believe that it is trying to override the normal deferred render order, but doesn't have enough depth information and just picks an arbitrary order each frame (perhaps due to floating point inaccuracy? Not certain, but it seems likely.)

Since you mention it's sorting properly on the Y axis, then assuming you're using the Y coordinate as an input to the layer depth, try adding a very small amount of the X coordinate as well. Assuming 32 by 32 tiles on screen, I would calculate the layer depth floating point value like this:

```
float depth = (someSprite.ScreenYCoord / 32) + (someSprite.ScreenXCoord / 1025);
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, sourceRect, color, rotation, origin, scale, spriteEffects, depth);
```

where 1025 is 32 * 32 + 1 (to make sure that a difference of 1 tile in Y is always more important when sorting than even a full 32 tiles difference in X) and assuming a zero-based screen coordinate system where something can be on tile 0 to 31 in either axis.

Also as far as I can tell ActiveMap.DrawAtDepth is not an XNA library function. Can you show us the code for that please, or show us wherever else the actual calls to SpriteBatch.Draw() are - that would help people work out what exactly is happening, and hopefully mean we have to guess less.

Comment: I added the rest of the code. Map calls Area, which are the nine currently active maps. Area calculates exactly which tiles to draw, and asks said Levels to draw the tiles on those positions. A Level consists of multiple layers, and said layers have a grid of tiles.

Comment: Adding a small value of the X coordinate has indeed seemed to fix it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that you've got it working! One final comment - if the problem comes up again with an especially huge level (thousands of tiles by thousands of tiles), it might be that you've run out of precision on the depth value, at which point you might have to switch to screen space coordinates rather than world space.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of spritebatch Begin() and End() is to ***minimize*** the amount of calls to it to increase performace, so it was concievedthat everything between 2 of them will be drawn in order. Change your code to this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
DrawBehind(spriteBatch);
DrawEven(spriteBatch);
DrawInFront(spriteBatch); 
spriteBatch.End();
```

and remove all instances of Begin() and End() in those functions.

If that doesn't help, check how ActiveMap.DrawAtDepth() works, but that should improve your program effciency in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The reason I put in three spriteBatches is so that the 'Behind' and 'InFront' calls do not have to use SpriteSortMode, they don't need to be sorted and can simply be drawn behind and in front.

The issue was more that the DrawEven draws are sorted wrongly, or seemingly at random. Efficiency is just fine~